# How can I get 12 cards in a page?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I do an app like SET card game(it is not finished),[I want to show 12 cards on a page from 81 cards I draw.But I try many times it can run successfully through,it crush suddenly.Is there any master can help me?

the setcardview is the class that collect 4 different features(number, shape, shading, color). I want to let my cards has base above features,like one purple worm,two green diamond,three orange oval etc.And then random show 12 cards in a page.

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val cardView = findViewById<SetCardView>(R.id.cardView)
        cardView.color = Color.RED
        cardView.number = 1
        cardView.shape = SetCardView.Shape.WORM
        cardView.shading = SetCardView.Shading.STRIP
    }
}
```

SetCardView.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.PointF
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.text.TextPaint
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import java.util.Random

class SetCardView(context: Context, private val parentLayout: LinearLayout) : View(context) {
    enum class Shape {
        OVAL, DIAMOND, WORM
    }

    enum class Shading {
        EMPTY, SOLID, STRIP
    }

    enum class Number {
        ONE, TWO, THREE
    }

    enum class Colors {
        PURPLE, BLUE, GREEN
    }

    public var number: Number = Number.ONE
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    public var shape = Shape.OVAL
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    public var color = Colors.PURPLE
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    public var shading = Shading.EMPTY
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    companion object {
        const val CARD_STANDARD_HEIGHT = 240.0f
        const val CORNER_RADIUS = 12.0f
        const val SYMBOL_WIDTH_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.6f
        const val SYMBOL_HEIGHT_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.125f
        const val STRIP_DISTANCE_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.05f
        const val ROW_COUNT = 9
        const val COLUMN_COUNT = 9
    }

    private val cornerScaleFactor: Float
        get() = height / CARD_STANDARD_HEIGHT

    private val cornerRadius: Float
        get() = CORNER_RADIUS * cornerScaleFactor

    private val mPaint = Paint() // For drawing border and face images
    private val mTextPaint = TextPaint() // for drawing pips (text)
    private val indexCount = Number.values().size * Shape.values().size * Colors.values().size * Shading.values().size

    init {
        mPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        mPaint.isSubpixelText = true
        mTextPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        mTextPaint.isSubpixelText = true
    }
    private fun drawShapeWithVerticalOffset(canvas: Canvas, voffset: Float) {
        val path = Path()
        val width = width * SYMBOL_WIDTH_SCALE_FACTOR
        val height = height * SYMBOL_HEIGHT_SCALE_FACTOR

        if (shape == Shape.OVAL) { // OVAL
            val center = PointF((getWidth() / 2).toFloat(), getHeight() / 2 + voffset)
            val left = center.x - width / 2
            val top = center.y - height / 2
            val right = center.x + width / 2
            val bottom = center.y + height / 2

            val ovalRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
            path.addOval(ovalRect, Path.Direction.CW)
        } else if (shape == Shape.DIAMOND) { // DIAMOND
            val center = PointF((getWidth() / 2).toFloat(), getHeight() / 2 + voffset)
            path.moveTo(center.x, center.y + height / 2)
            path.lineTo(center.x + width / 2, center.y)
            path.lineTo(center.x, center.y - height / 2)
            path.lineTo(center.x - width / 2, center.y)
            path.close()
        } else { // WORM
            val center = PointF((getWidth() / 2).toFloat(), getHeight() / 2 + voffset)
            path.moveTo(center.x - width / 2, center.y + height / 2)

            val cp1 = PointF(center.x - width / 4, center.y - height * 1.5f)
            val cp2 = PointF(center.x + width / 4, center.y)
            val dst = PointF(center.x + width / 2, center.y - height / 2)
            path.cubicTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, dst.x, dst.y)

            cp1.x = center.x + width / 2
            cp1.y = center.y + height * 2
            cp2.x = center.x - width / 2
            cp2.y = center.y

            dst.x = center.x - width / 2
            dst.y = center.y + height / 2

            path.cubicTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, dst.x, dst.y)
        }
        drawShadingInPath(canvas, path)
        drawShapes(canvas, path)
    }
    private fun drawShapes(canvas: Canvas, path:Path) {
        val width = width * SYMBOL_WIDTH_SCALE_FACTOR
        val height = height * SYMBOL_HEIGHT_SCALE_FACTOR

        val center = PointF(width / 2, height / 2)

        for (i in 0 until number.ordinal + 1) { // Draw the specified number of shapes
            val voffset = height / 2 * (i + 1)
            val path = Path()
            when (shape) {
                Shape.OVAL -> {
                    val left = center.x - width / 2
                    val top = center.y - height / 2 + voffset
                    val right = center.x + width / 2
                    val bottom = center.y + height / 2 + voffset

                    val ovalRect = RectF(left, top, right, bottom)
                    path.addOval(ovalRect, Path.Direction.CW)
                }

                Shape.DIAMOND -> {
                    path.moveTo(center.x, center.y + height / 2 + voffset)
                    path.lineTo(center.x + width / 2, center.y + voffset)
                    path.lineTo(center.x, center.y - height / 2 + voffset)
                    path.lineTo(center.x - width / 2, center.y + voffset)
                    path.close()
                }

                Shape.WORM -> {
                    path.moveTo(center.x - width / 2, center.y + height / 2 + voffset)

                    val cp1 = PointF(center.x - width / 4, center.y - height * 1.5f + voffset)
                    val cp2 = PointF(center.x + width / 4, center.y + voffset)
                    val dst = PointF(center.x + width / 2, center.y - height / 2 + voffset)
                    path.cubicTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, dst.x, dst.y)

                    cp1.x = center.x + width / 2
                    cp1.y = center.y + height * 2 + voffset
                    cp2.x = center.x - width / 2
                    cp2.y = center.y + voffset

                    dst.x = center.x - width / 2
                    dst.y = center.y + height / 2 + voffset

                    path.cubicTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, dst.x, dst.y)
                }
            }
            drawShadingInPath(canvas, path)
        }
    }
    private fun drawShadingInPath(canvas: Canvas, path: Path) {
        mPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        mPaint.color = when (color) {
            Colors.PURPLE -> Color.rgb(154, 18, 179)
            Colors.BLUE -> Color.rgb(18, 106, 179)
            Colors.GREEN -> Color.rgb(18, 179, 31)
        }

        when (shading) {
            Shading.EMPTY -> {
                canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint)
            }

            Shading.SOLID -> {
                canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint)
            }

            Shading.STRIP -> {
                val stripDistance = width * STRIP_DISTANCE_SCALE_FACTOR
                var x = 0f
                while (x < width) {
                    path.moveTo(x, 0f)
                    path.lineTo(x, height.toFloat())
                    x += stripDistance
                }
                canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val rect = RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        val path = Path()
        path.addRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)

        // fill
        mPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        mPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint)
        // border
        mPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mPaint.strokeWidth = 3.0f
        mPaint.color = Color.BLACK
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint)

        val cardWidth = width / COLUMN_COUNT
        val cardHeight = height / ROW_COUNT

        for (i in 0 until ROW_COUNT) {
            for (j in 0 until COLUMN_COUNT) {
                val cardIndex = i * COLUMN_COUNT + j
                val index = cardIndex % indexCount

                // Calculate the card properties based on the index
                val number = Number.values()[index % Number.values().size]
                val shape = Shape.values()[(index / Number.values().size) % Shape.values().size]
                val color =
                    Colors.values()[(index / (Number.values().size * Shape.values().size)) % Colors.values().size]
                val shading =
                    Shading.values()[(index / (Number.values().size * Shape.values().size * Colors.values().size)) % Shading.values().size]

                val left = j * cardWidth + paddingLeft
                val top = i * cardHeight + paddingTop
                val right = left + cardWidth
                val bottom = top + cardHeight
            }
        }
    }
    fun setRandomCards() {
        val cardList = mutableListOf<Pair<Number, Shape>>() // Create a list to hold the card attributes
        val random = Random()

        // Generate 12 unique random cards
        while (cardList.size < 12) {
            val number = Number.values()[random.nextInt(Number.values().size)]
            val shape = Shape.values()[random.nextInt(Shape.values().size)]
            val pair = Pair(number, shape)

            if (!cardList.contains(pair)) {
                cardList.add(pair)
            }
        }
        // Shuffle the cardList to display the cards randomly
        cardList.shuffle()

        // Set the cards in the SetCardView
        for (i in 0 until cardList.size) {
            val number = cardList[i].first
            val shape = cardList[i].second
            val cardView = SetCardView(context, parentLayout)
            cardView.number = number
            cardView.shape = shape
            cardView.color = Colors.PURPLE
            cardView.shading = shading

            // Calculate the card's position in the grid
            val cardWidth = width / COLUMN_COUNT
            val cardHeight = height / ROW_COUNT
            val column = i % COLUMN_COUNT
            val row = i / COLUMN_COUNT
            val left = column * cardWidth + paddingLeft
            val top = row * cardHeight + paddingTop
            val right = left + cardWidth
            val bottom = top + cardHeight

            cardView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(cardWidth, cardHeight)
            cardView.layout(left, top, right, bottom)
            parentLayout.addView(cardView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a repo at least? This is not enough information. What is the error that you get?

Comment: I run this many times,it actually can run successfully but it suddenly crush.
This is not only file.I have the other file--MainActivity.kt

Comment: Now,it seems run better than before.It only can show a pattern which has one red worm.